# Styling the can_delete form checkbox in model formset factory django

Tags: python, django

forms.py

```
from .models import Bacteria, Citation
from django.forms import ModelForm, modelformset_factory,
from django import forms

class CitationForm(ModelForm):
    citation = forms.CharField(label=False)
    citation.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control','placeholder': 'Source'})
    

    class Meta:
        model = Citation
        fields = ('citation',)

        widgets = {'citation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Reference'})

        }
CitationFormset = modelformset_factory(Citation, form=CitationForm, extra=0, can_delete=True)
```

For each form instance in the model form set factory, the check box which sets a form in the formset works perfectly fine but has default styling. Is there any way to style the check box and I know the input field is named "DELETE" but I do not know how to style and give the class (for the checkbox for each form) that I want.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet.deletion_widget You need to just create a base formset, override `get_deletion_widget` there to specify classes/whatever you need (`return CheckboxInput(attrs={...})`), and pass that base formset to `modelformset_factory`.

Comment: Yea that worked. I originally thought it was a boolean field since the 'DELETE' field consists of a boolean but it turned out instead I had to used checkbox input. Thanks for the help!